# Adobe Payment Service - 3d Secure card is not working

Tags: magento2, payment

I have configured Sandbox Adobe payment service successfully. Normal card are working fine but when I enabled 3d secure from configuration then for 3d authentication cards popup is coming and then it is closing without success and below error is coming.

> Your payment was not successful. Ensure you have entered your details correctly and try again, or try a different payment method. If you have continued problems, contact the issuing bank for your payment method.

I checked in network tab and found these both url is throwing 400 error
sandbox.paypal.com/webapps/helios/api/switch/threeDSLookUp
centinelapi.cardinalcommerce.com/V1/Cruise/Collect

I have used below 3d secure cards and more from card generator
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/advanced/customize/3d-secure/test/

Sometimes api/switch/threeDSLookUp is giving below response

```
  {
      "ack": "success",
      "data": {
          "transactionId": "21681440094526826",
          "threeDSVersion": "",
          "enrollmentStatus": "UNKNOWN",
          "liabilityShift": false,
          "threeDSEcommerceIndicator": null,
          "cardBrandProcessed": null,
          "signatureVerificationStatus": "NO",
          "threeDSStatus": "UNKNOWN",
          "paymentAuthenticationRequest": "",
          "acsURL": {
              "href": null
          },
          "redirectURL": {
              "href": null
          },
          "transactionStatusCode": "MISSING_BUSINESS_RULE_OR_DATA",
          "transactionStatusMessage": "The client provided invalid request data.",
          "threeDsServerTransactionId": null,
          "threeDsAuthenticationReason": null,
          "threeDSUcafIndicator": "",
          "authenticationThreeDSStatus": null,
          "threeDsProcessorTraceNumber": null,
          "cavv": null,
          "cavvAlgorithm": null,
          "xid": null,
          "paypalAcquiringBin": null,
          "paypalAcquiringMid": null,
          "accessControlServerTransactionId": null,
          "acquirerScaExemptionIndicators": [],
          "dsTransactionId": null
      },
      "meta": {
          "calc": "f822469e85afa",
          "rlog": "rZJvnqaaQhLn%2FnmWT8cSUg9MBfMHgUpSmljgVb0XwipLideqzjUNiu0dbKC466eQpEWP0DFUgeY_18cb0f34b8c"
      },
      "server": "Q5B1oeUuRQ7NMtcjex9G-lbeaDae7yfL2UjCJys8LLJU3zZ9pgiw0u1KeJxyzDhbstpxjw6SdB666kv3IpI1XxObW7Yb6e6QsBWrBYbMEe8UmDQodkur_WdQ6HYzywymZ2Bjos_XCyhq5hRbCcy9IEO_vjPK1nqjJh5Ns-Dkby5P00kkMicwaVJjUMl1exQLJ4hbgLK-Tw5LFDbFMLvFqrsNZcPKrjH2RrOkOZdvJH3_ljXoe5Epi9_OMDbTsU2W"
  }
```

Comment: Can you please tell me where you got the Sandbox Adobe payment service  and where to add